# Python pandas dataframe "Date" Index different format in xlsx and csv

Tags: python, excel, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have an xlsx file with multiple tabs, each tab has a `Date` column in the format of `MM/DD/YYYY`

Read each tab into a pandas dataframe, applied some operations on each tab, and then write the dataframe back into two formats: xlsx and csv

In the xlsx file, the `Date` column (index) becomes a format that has the time attached: `1/1/2013  12:00:00 AM`, while the `Date` column in the csv file remains unchanged: `MM/DD/YYYY`

How can I make sure the `Date` column in the xlsx file maintains the same format `MM/DD/YYYY`?

Comment: Excel read system setting, so it will vary machine to machine.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the datetime in the default pandas Excel datetime format. However, you can easily set it to whatever you want:

```
# Set the default datetime and/or date formats.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_datetime.xlsx",
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        date_format='mm/dd/yyy',
                        datetime_format='mm/dd/yyyy')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

See a full example in the XlsxWriter docs: Example: [Pandas Excel output with date times.](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date to a string.  If the date is in the index, you could do:

```
df.set_index(df.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))).to_excel()
```