# How to preserve date format when creating an Excel file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an .xlsx file that I import into Python and create a Pandas dataframe. One of the columns in the .xlsx file is formatted as a date, **mm-dd-yyyy** and gets imported like that. I then delete some unneeded columns from that dataframe and export that dataframe using the xlsxwriter engine to create another Excel file.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Sample_Master_Data_edited.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', date_format='mm/dd/yyyy')
```

When I do that, the date column's format changes and time automatically gets added to the date column. The cells in the column then follow this format, **yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss**.

I found a potential [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713729/python-pandas-dataframe-date-index-different-format-in-xlsx-and-csv) but when I tried the code below,

```
df.set_index(df.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))).to_excel()
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

I also [read](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) that it isn't possible to format any cells that already have a default format applied.

Is this a lost cause? How can I preserve the pre-existing date format upon export as an .xlsx file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Sample_Master_Data_edited.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', 
                        date_format='mm/dd/yyyy', datetime_format='mm/dd/yyyy')
```