# Changing date-format to text in xlsx using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have written a script that reads from excel workbooks and writes new workbooks.
Each row is a separate object, and one of the columns is a date.
I have written the date as a NamedStyle using datetime to get what I think is the correct format:

```
    date_style = NamedStyle(name='datetime', number_format='YYYY-MM-DD')
    for row in range(2,ws_kont.max_row+1):
        ws_kont.cell(row = row, column = 4).style = date_style
```

The problem is that i need to import this excel workbook to an ancient database who for some reason dont accept a date-formating, only text like this "yyyy-dd-mm".
I'm having trouble rewriting these cells as text.

I have tried using the =TEXT formula, but that wont work since you cant use the cell itself to calculate the result unless i duplicate the column for referencing in the formula:

```
name = str(ws_teg.cell(row = row, column = 4).coordinate)
date_f = "yyyy-mm-dd"
ws_kont[name] = "=TEXT(%s,%s)" % (name, date_f)
```

I need to do this a bunch of places in a couple of scripts, so I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do this?

PS. I'm just a archaeologist trying to automate some tasks in my workday by dabbling in some simple code, please go easy on me if I seem a bit slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, it won't be enough to change the *format* of your date - you'll have to store the date as a string instead of a datetime object.

Loop over the column and format the dates with [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
for row in range(1, ws_kont.max_row+1):
    cell = ws_kont.cell(row = row, column = 4)
    cell.value = cell.value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: When something feels like its supposed to be simple, it usually is. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

Found another article that worked out well with minmal code:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Sample_Master_Data_edited.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', 
                        date_format='mm/dd/yyyy', datetime_format='mm/dd/yyyy')
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354065/how-to-preserve-date-format-when-creating-an-excel-file)