# Python maintain date format when exporting from csv to xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, csv, time, openpyxl

I'm using the `csv` module to export data from a large number of raw data files in csv format into an excel template. I'm having an issue with how the dates are being exported, trying to plot a graph from the dates gives the following where the x axis shows only 00:00 rather than the changing times. Dates are in format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm.

[image: Excel date graph]

I'm using this code with openpyxl and csv:

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
import csv

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

with open('Date Test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        ws.append(row)

wb.save('excel date.xlsx')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354065/how-to-preserve-date-format-when-creating-an-excel-file

Comment: ReadTheFineManual [using-number-formats](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-number-formats). Keep in mind `CSV` is **TEXT** only.

Comment: What is shown in Excel file for the dates? It may depend on your locale settings...

Comment: CSV has no typing or formatting. You have to decide how you want to do this yourself. This, and encoding problems, make CSV unsuited for generic data transfer.